# Override Dashboard in TYPO3

Tags: php, typo3, fluid

Im trying to override the `help_AboutmodulesAboutmodules`iframe in TYPO3.
I think that is the initial page when you are log in as backend user.

I override the Route, so I can set an own Controller.
And in my controller I set the templatePath to my own index.html

```
 'help_AboutmodulesAboutmodules' => [
    'access' => 'public',
    'target' => Controller\EditorOverviewController::class . '::getEditorOverview',
],


public function getEditorOverview()
{
    $view = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(StandaloneView::class);
    $view->setLayoutRootPaths([GeneralUtility::getFileAbsFileName('EXT:backend/Resources/Private/Layouts')]);
    $view->setTemplateRootPaths(
        [GeneralUtility::getFileAbsFileName('EXT:backend/Resources/Private/Templates/EditorOverview')]
    );
    $view->setTemplatePathAndFilename(
        GeneralUtility::getFileAbsFileName(
            'EXT:backend/Resources/Private/Templates/EditorOverview/Index.html'
        )
    );
    $rendered = $view->render();
    echo $rendered;
}
```

Is this the right way?

And how can I add the TYPO3 own bootstrap to the iframe or maybe javascript?

Comment: Why not register a custom BE module and simply change the default module for the user in question in its settings?

Comment: Depending on your TYPO3 CMS Version you can set the default start page of a backend user in the User settings ("Startup").

Comment: Its TYPO3 7.6.31, but will be updatet to v8.